# Way to use JavaScript to check browsers such like window, safari and chrome

Tags: javascript, filesaver.js

I have a problem about using the following code to check browser

```
view =(
            typeof self !== "undefined" && self ||
            typeof window !== "undefined" && window ||
            this.content
        ); 
is_safari = /constructor/i.test(view.HTMLElement) || view.safari,
is_chrome_ios = /CriOS\/[\d]+/.test(navigator.userAgent),
```

The upper code snippet is from FileSaver.js, and the problem is what is the meaning of /constructor/i.test, it seems the javascipt api not include 
this function. Is there anyone know about that, thanks a lot.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to detect Safari, Chrome, IE, Firefox and Opera browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9847580/how-to-detect-safari-chrome-ie-firefox-and-opera-browser)

Comment: If you test it with safari put `alert(view.HTMLElement);` and if you use chrome put `alert(navigator.userAgent);` after `view = (...)` Then tell us what alert shows to you.

Comment: I use console.info(view.HTMLElement); and I got "function HTMLElement() { [native code] }"; and then navigator.userAgent, I got "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (
KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.112 Safari/537.36 OPR/36.0.213"; thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- `/pattern/` is a [regular expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) literal
- `i` is a flag that makes it case insensitive
- `test` is [a method found on regular expression objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test)

It is standard JavaScript.

Comment: `test is a method found on regular expression objects` do you mean it looks for test into `/pattern/`? If no could you provide a very simple example about it please?

Comment: No. There are examples in the documentation I linked to (and in the code in the question!)